# Drupal 7 Exposed filter jquery drag and drop form

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I need to create jquery based drag and drop exposed filter.
I have a filter that sorts my recipies by ingridient id, what i need to do is to create a drag and drop interface where users can drag and drop an ingridient image and get the filter going.

How can this be implemented in views? Was thinking to create two different views one with a list of ingridients (draggable) another with an exposed filter (droppable) and then stucked.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the exposed form provided by views and use the view with the draggable elements to map the exposed form avail values. 
Seems to me more a jQuery UI related thing than a drupal one.